# usr/bin/lpr: Too many active jobs

Tags: macos, lpr

I try to print with a receipt printer.
It all worked fine but I was sending prints to quick to the device.

Now I get the error:

`usr/bin/lpr: Too many active jobs`

I would like to clear all active jobs. I tried rebooting and turning the device on and off, but it does not help.

The complete error is:

```
RuntimeException: javax.print.PrintException: java.io.IOException: error=1 running: '/usr/bin/lpr' '-PEPSON_TM_T88V' '-J Java Printing' '-o media=Letter' '/var/folders/fb/fnzlgb7d2p7_h4gspnvdldzr0000gn/T/javaprint159865029725996489'
        /usr/bin/lpr: Too many active jobs.
```

Is there any way to clear the current jobs?

lpr has the following options:

```
Usage: lpr [options] [file(s)]
Options:
-# num-copies           Specify the number of copies to print
-E                      Encrypt the connection to the server
-H server[:port]        Connect to the named server and port
-m                      Send an email notification when the job completes
-o option[=value]       Specify a printer-specific option
-o job-sheets=standard  Print a banner page with the job
-o media=size           Specify the media size to use
-o number-up=N          Specify that input pages should be printed N-up (1, 2, 4, 6, 9, and 16 are supported)
-o orientation-requested=N
                        Specify portrait (3) or landscape (4) orientation
-o print-quality=N      Specify the print quality - draft (3), normal (4), or best (5)
-o sides=one-sided      Specify 1-sided printing
-o sides=two-sided-long-edge
                        Specify 2-sided portrait printing
-o sides=two-sided-short-edge
                        Specify 2-sided landscape printing
-P destination          Specify the destination
-q                      Specify the job should be held for printing
-r                      Remove the file(s) after submission
-T title                Specify the job title
-U username             Specify the username to use for authentication
```

Comment: Asking this on SuperUser or [Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com) is probably a better fit. Or maybe even [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com), lpr (in this case part of CUPS) is not specific to macOS.

Comment: Do [lpq](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lpq-cups) and [lprm](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lprm.html) help?